# Tcolorbox: force labelling to take on specific number

Tags: labels, tcolorbox

Using tcolorbox, how can I label a box and give the box whatever number I want?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox[use counter=table,number within=chapter]{MijnOtherBox}[2][]{breakable,coltitle=blue!20!black,colback=black!1!white,colframe=black!10!white,title={Box~\thetcbcounter: #2},#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{MijnOtherBox}[label=Boxone]{Title for the box}
I want this box to be labelled with number 3.1 instead of \ref{Boxone}
\end{MijnOtherBox}

\end{document}
```

In fact my problem is that in my document there is an issue with the numbering of the boxes: in some chapters the numbering jump, e.g. Box 3.1, Box 3.2 and (!) Box 3.4, skipping 3.3...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the problem is skipping some values or setting them. This answer can help in the first case.

If you just want to skip one value, next code shows two possibilities:

- `\stepcounter` outside the box or
- `step and label` as `tcolorbox` option.

If you need to jump more than one value, use `\addtocounter` before the box.

Remember that the new value will be the base for following boxes.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox[use counter=table,number within=chapter]{MijnOtherBox}[2][]
    {breakable, coltitle=blue!20!black, colback=black!1!white, 
    colframe=black!10!white, title={Box~\thetcbcounter: #2}, #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{MijnOtherBox}[label=Boxone1]{Title for the box}
I want this box to be labelled with number 3.1 instead of \ref{Boxone1}
\end{MijnOtherBox}

\stepcounter{table}
\begin{MijnOtherBox}[label=Boxone2]{Title for the box}
I want this box to be labelled with number 3.1 instead of \ref{Boxone2}
\end{MijnOtherBox}

\begin{MijnOtherBox}[step and label={table}{Boxone3}]{Title for the box}
I want this box to be labelled with number 3.1 instead of \ref{Boxone3}
\end{MijnOtherBox}

\addtocounter{table}{3}
\begin{MijnOtherBox}[label=Boxone4]{Title for the box}
I want this box to be labelled with number 3.1 instead of \ref{Boxone4}
\end{MijnOtherBox}

\end{document}
```

[image]